# Screen blinking to black on 20.04

Tags: xorg, wine, intel, 20.04

Basically, since I upgraded to 20.04 from 19.10, my screen sometimes blinks to black for about a second then back to normal for a bit, and blinks again and then works as expected. The issue happens on the login screen, right after login and when running a .exe through Wine. It might also happen in other scenarios but I haven't encountered it elsewhere as of yet.

I've tried running on both Xorg and Wayland (I typically use X though), on both the Ubuntu session and the "stock" Gnome session, same result everywhere.

I'm running on a Dell XPS 13 2 in 1 7390, which has an Icelake Intel processor (1065G7). I could deal with the issue if it only happened at login (it doesn't happen when waking up from sleep on the lockscreen, and I don't reboot *that* often), but I run quite a lot of .exe games and while the issue fades right after the game is started up it is still quite annoying.

I'd appreciate it a lot if someone could point me to the right log files to help me diagnose what's happening, if someone has an idea of how to fix it that'd be even better obviously.

Cheers !

Edit: Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` as requested:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07)
    DeviceName: To Be Filled by O.E.M.
    Subsystem: Dell Iris Plus Graphics G7
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: I edited my question with the information you requested, hope that helps you to help me.

Comment: Where is the first line of the output?

Comment: Sorry I put the code markers one line early and they ate the first line for some reason, you have everything now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for what it's worth the issue has now vanished on its own. Not too sure of what changed, most likely that whatever was causing it got fixed by some update, but it's gone. Not really an answer but might as well disclose that my particular issue is no more.